# Does there exists biholomorphic map(with suitable condition) from domain to open disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Put $D=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|<1\}$ (open disk).  We define  $f:D\to D$ as $f(z)=z,$ for all $z\in D,$  which is clearly [biholomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biholomorphism).

> **My Question is**:
> (1) For any $z_0\in D,$  can we choose a map $f_{z_{0}}: D \to D$ which is bihlomorphic and satisfies the condition $f_{z_0}(z_0)=0$ and $f'_{z_0}(z_0)>0.$  Is this map unique?
>
> (2) If we start with arbitrary biholomorphic map $h:\Omega \to D$ (where $\Omega$ is non empty open connected subset of $\mathbb C$). Can we expect a  analogous conclusion as in (1)? In other words, for every $z_{0}\in \Omega ,$ does there exist unique biholomorphic map $h_{z_0}: \Omega \to \mathbb C$  such that $h_{z_{0}}(z_0)=0$ and $h'_{z_{0}}(z_0)>0$?

Comment: You might want to check out the Riemann mapping theoren.

Comment: @Hirshy; thanks, but Reimann mapping theorem is for simply connected domain; how does it help here?

Comment: My bad, I thought/misread that in (2) you were referring to simple connected subsets as well.

Comment: Why did you define the map $f$? It doesn't appear anywhere after that...

Comment: @NI; thanks; I just thought of simplest possible example which is valid for $z_{0}=0$. Kindly point out me if I have missed something or if question does not make sense; thanks

Answer (score 2):

(1) The map
$$
f(z) = e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z}
$$
is a biholomorphic self map of the unit disk that sends $z_0$ to $0$. As you can see it is not unique with a free variable $\theta$.

The requirement $f'(z_0)>0$ doesn't make sense to me, since $f'(z_0)$ is a complex number. If you're talking about $\| f'(z_0)\|$, since $f$ is biholomorphic its derivative is nowhere $0$.

(2) A biholomorphism is also a homeomorphism, so if $\Omega$ and $D$ were biholomorphic, they are homeomorphic, hence $\Omega$ must be simply connected. Then the Riemann mapping theorem tells us that $h$ is unique up to an automorphism of $D$.

Comment: In complex analysis the condition $c>0$ for a complex number $c$ is interpreted as "$\>c$ is real and $>0\>$".

Comment: @Quidi: thanks a lot; would you please explain a bit more? ((i)Is simply connectedness is a topological property? (ii) By [RMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) we have existence but why unique upto automorphism of $D$? (iii) What are automorphis of $D$ ? any reference?)

Comment: If $f$ is biholomorphic then why its derivative is nowhere zero?

Comment: Choose $g_{z_0}$ with the same property; then $h=f_{z_0}\circ g_{z_0}^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ mapping $0$ to $0$, so $h$ is a rotation $h(z)=e^{i\theta}z$. Note that $h\circ g_{z_0}=f_{z_0}$ and differentiate both sides at $z_0$ to get $h'(0)g'_{z_0}(z_0)=f_{z_0}'(z_0)$ and by positivity, $h'(0)>0$ so $\theta=0\to h(z)=z\to f_{z_0}=g_{z_0}$.

Comment: Also, the automorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$ are $e^{i\theta}\frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}$. To clarify: $f_{z_0}$ is **unique** with the condition $f_{z_0}'(z_0)>0$, or unique up to automorphism without this condition.

Comment: @Michael M; Thanks a lot: Given $z_0\in \Omega,$ and since $\Omega $ is simply connected(as shown above), by RMT it is clear to me that there exist biholomorphic map $h_{z_0}: \Omega \to \mathbb D$; but after this I am unable to follow (why $h_{z_0}(z_0)=0$ and $h'_{z_0}(z_0)>0 $? how to choose such $h_{z_0}$ ? )  Thanks

Comment: RMT states that there exists a biholomorphic map $h_{z_0}:\Omega\to\mathbb{D}$ with $h_{z_0}(z_0)=0$ and $h_{z_0}'(z_0)>0$, and that this map is unique. (There exist other biholomorphic maps from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{D}$ without these other two properties.) Finding the actual map $h_{z_0}$ is often difficult; all we know is that it exists by RMT.

Comment: @Inquisitive (i) yes simply connectedness is a topological condition (ii) Let $f$, $g$ be two Riemann maps, then $\varphi = f\circ g^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $D$, and  $f = \varphi \circ g$. (iii) Michael gave the answer, you can probably find references by just googling automorphisms of the unit disk

Comment: @Inquisitive The fact that the conditions $h_{z_0}(z_0)=0$ and $h_{z_0}'(z_0)>0$(in fact just the argument) uniquely determines $h_{z_0}$ follows from Schwarz lemma, which Michael uses implicitly in his proof.