# Find all biholomorphic applications $\phi : S \to D$ such that $\phi(2)= 0,\phi(3) < 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Hello I tried this problem without success, could someone help me ?
Let $S =\{z \in\mathbb{C}\mid \Re (z) > | \Im (z)| \}$ and let $D$ be the unit disk.
Find all biholomorphic applications $\phi : S \to D$ such that $\phi(2)= 0,\phi(3) < 0$.
What i know is the existence of biholomorphic application between $ S$ and $S\cap D$

Comment: *Hint:* Start with $z \mapsto z^2$, which maps $S$ to a half-plane.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR  it seems $\phi(z)=\frac{4-z^2}{4+z^2}$ is a solution  how to find all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consequence of the Riemann mapping theorem tells us that the map transforming a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ to another is unique up to an automorphism of the disk [(see here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369729/does-there-exists-biholomorphic-mapwith-suitable-condition-from-domain-to-open). Since you already found a solution in the comments you can readily verify it's uniqueness as follows:

[A disk automorphism](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/automorphisms-of-the-unit-disc#:%7E:text=Theorem%3A%20Every%20automorphism%20f%20of,Proof.) is a Moebius transformation of the form:

$$g(z)=\frac{az+b}{\bar{b}z+\bar{a}}~~,~~ |a|^2-|b|^2=1$$

Since by the mapping theorem the map is unique up to automorphisms and your solution saitisfies all the conditions, we only need to prove that the only disk automorphism that preserves the conditions is the identity.

Demanding that $(g\circ\phi)(2)=0$ shows that $b=0$ and hence $g(z)=e^{i\theta}z$.  Now imposing $(g\circ\phi)(3)=-\frac{5}{13}e^{i\theta}<0$ shows that $\theta=0$ and hence the map you found is the unique solution.